# CSS - UL parent is smaller then child

Tags: html, css

Hey guys i am using simple ul li to style 3 short artiles,things looks good but problem is that i noticed that UL parent is not on full size and li is bigger then it (what is not good :P)

Can somebody try to help me to fix it? And make that with same width , height as its childs?

it looks like: 
[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="article-container">

<ul>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/foto.jpg" width="109" height="109" alt="Popis"></a>
            <h2><a href="#">Název článku</a></h2>
            <p><span><strong>28. 2. 2014 8:29</strong> od Dwandy</span><br>
              Ahoj, jak se máš? Já úplně úžasně a úpe nejvíc. Závidíš, he? </p>
            <p class="more"><a href="#" class="links">Přečíst</a><br>
              <a href="#">4 reakce</a></p>
            <hr>
       </li>

  <li><a href="#"><img src="images/foto.jpg" alt="Popis"></a>
           <h2><a href="#">Název článku</a></h2>
           <p><span><strong>28. 2. 2014 8:29</strong> od Dwandy</span><br>
             Ahoj, jak se máš? Já úplně úžasně a úpe nejvíc. Závidíš, he? </p>
           <p class="more"><a href="#" class="links">Přečíst</a><br>
             <a href="#">4 reakce</a></p>
           <hr>
      </li>

      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/foto.jpg" alt="Popis"></a>
           <h2><a href="#">Název článku</a></h2>
           <p><span><strong>28. 2. 2014 8:29</strong> od Dwandy</span><br>
             Ahoj, jak se máš? Já úplně úžasně a úpe nejvíc. Závidíš, he? </p>
           <p class="more"><a href="#" class="links">Přečíst</a><br>
             <a href="#">4 reakce</a></p>
           <hr>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#article-container{
  width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:#4d4d4d;
    font-size:90%;
  height: 144px;
}

#article-container br, hr {
    display:none;
}
#article-container ul {
    width:960px;
  height: 144px
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:15px 0;
}
#article-container li {
    width:310px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 8px;
}
#article-container img {
    float:left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0
}
#article-container a img {
    border:2px solid #999e8a
}
#article-container a:hover img {
    border-color:#000
}
#article-container h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    font-size:110%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
#article-container h2 a {
    color:#4d4d4d
}
#article-container h2 a:hover {
    color:#840000
}
#article-container p {
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    margin:0
}
#article-container p span {
    display:block;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0
}
#article-container p.more {
    padding: 0px 0 0 0;
    overflow:hidden
}


#article-container p.more a {
    color:#2e79bc;
    line-height: 27px;
}
#article-container p.more a:hover {
    color:#840000
}
#article-container p.more a.links {
    float:right;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background:#2e79bc;
    color:#fff;
    margin-right:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius:3px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
#article-container p.more a.links:hover {
    background:#000
}
```

p.s. Thanks for reading this post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't float the list elements but make them `display: inline-block;` and the height will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, if super simple-sounding to you!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's mostly likely the result of the `li` tags being `float: left`

Try making them `display: inline-block` instead, perhaps, which won't make the parent container collapse the way `float` will.

Comment: Aw, got tangled up in the reCaptcha, and KittMedia beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using a common fix in css called a clearfix.
Make a class like so and put it on the parent containing floated elements.

```
/**
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that are clearfixed.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

[Reference](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)

Answer (score 0):

`inline-block` would work

but if u want to keep them as `float:left` add this list element after the list item `<li style="clear:both"></li>`

or to be precise use the `clearfix` class on the `<ul>` and add this in css(if u are using this no need to add the list element shown above).

```
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
* html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```